# Set geofence radius to 200m, but Triggering location is at 50m distance from the geofence center. Why?

Tags: android, gps, location, geofencing, android-geofence

This is how I create the Geofence:

```
   ArrayList geofences = new ArrayList<>();
        geofences.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(geofenceRequestID)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setCircularRegion(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), radius)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .build());
```

Where: `geofenceRequestID = "1";` and the radius is: 200;

This is how I add the geofences:

```
  mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(location, geofences), getGeofencePendingIntent(context)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    isSettingGeofence = false;
                    Utils.makeNotification(context, "GEOFENCE ADDED: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), true);
                    PSLocationService.getInstance(context).setTrackingEnabled(false);
                    Utils.appendLog(context, "Geofence Transitions Service setGeofenceRequest Success adding geofences!" +
                                    location.getLatitude() +
                                    " , " + location.getLongitude(),
                            "I",
                            Constants.GEOFENCE);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    isSettingGeofence = false;
                    Utils.appendLog(context, "Geofence Transitions Service setGeofenceRequest FAILURE adding geofences!" +
                                    e.getMessage(),
                            "E",
                            Constants.GEOFENCE);
                }
            });
```

Now on handle intent. I do this:

```
  Location triggering = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
        if(triggering != null) {
            Utils.appendLog(PSGeofenceTransitionsIntentService.this, "GEOFENCE onHandleIntent got an EXIT transition: " + triggering.getLatitude() + ", " + triggering.getLongitude() + "/ " + triggering.getAccuracy(), "D", Constants.GEOFENCE);
        }
```

I got to this case:

```
2017-10-17 14:38:32.615 30908:30908 [I] psngr.TRACKER.geofence Geofence Transitions Service setGeofenceRequest Success adding geofences! 52.37040665000001 , 4.9299061
2017-10-17 14:39:18.664 30908:8765 [D] psngr.TRACKER.geofence GEOFENCE onHandleIntent got an EXIT transition: 52.370363, 4.9306961/ 899.999
```

If you check the distance between them: https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/52.370363,+4.9306961/52.3704067,4.9299061/@52.370435,4.9300744,18.8z/data=!4m7!4m6!1m3!2m2!1d4.9306961!2d52.370363!1m0!3e3
Or with: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/calculators it gives you a 54m distance.
Now I see that the accuracy of my triggering location is 899.999 but shouldn't the geofence mechanism take that in account? Is this a bug, do I need to raise it to google somehow? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `the accuracy of my triggering location is 899.999`. Units please.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()
Accuracy "Get the estimated horizontal accuracy of this location, radial, in meters." "We define horizontal accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence"

Comment: So you are 54 meters away of the centre of your geofence and you get a message that you are leaving that geofence which has a radius of 200 meter?

Comment: I have never seen a gps device with an accuracy of nearly a km. So where does yours come from? If the accuracy is like that you should not complain.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
Geofencing API does not use the GPS. It is there specifically, to let the user know when he leaves, or enters a POI. Which can then if needed activate the gps (I request location updates as soon as my geofence is triggered).
I'm not expecting Geofencing to have a good accuracy, using network location and triangulation. BUT I do expect it to atleast wait till it's out of the 200m radius I've set. That is what the API says it does

Comment: PS: I've did the testing and found this issue on a Nexus 5, LG G5 and Le Eco Pro 2. So it is not a hardware related issue. I'm hoping from this question to get an insight on how this works. Is this something that is known to happen, or do I need to raise a ticket with Google?

Comment: `Geofencing API does not use the GPS`  ?? Geofencing looks only at locations. How they are provided is a different story. If you dont use gps and rely on wifi and accuracy is bad then all ends.

Comment: well when geofencing is triggered, it will use the gps after that. but the whole point of the geofence, is that when you are stationary, you set a geofence circle, and when you get a location outside of it, it will ask for gps accurate locations. BUT that is not my question. My question is, why is it triggered, with only a 50m difference. If the Geofencing triggering mode, doesn't take in account the accuracy, can I force it to take it in account?

Comment: Think that it takes into account accuracy.